# How to show a specific DIV based on variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that loads the following Javascript object **fields**:

```
var fields = {"age":"on","email":"useremail@gmail.com","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","officialrules":"on","question":"a"};
```

As you can see, the last property contains the variable **question** and the value **a**.

In the HTML I have three divs, each containing a style of display:none.

```
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
```

Using Javascript, I would like to show the div based on the value in the **question**. So for example, if the value = a, I want the display of div1 to change to block. If the value = b, I want the display of div2 to change to block, and if the value = c, I want the display of div 3 to change to block.

I am very new to Javascript, so not sure what is the best way to approach this. That being said, when I play around in the browser console, I'm able to achieve this effect using the following line:

```
if (fields.question == 'a') {document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';}
```

How can I write a script that will show a specific div based on the variable in my Javascript? I am assuming I'll have to use an if... then... else OR switch type of statement. Do I need to first declare three variables and get the Element By Id for the 3 divs? My first line of thinking is something like this... but I'm clearly stuck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var a = document.getElementById('div1');
    var b = document.getElementById('div2');
    var c = document.getElementById('div3');

        if (fields.question == 'a') {document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';} 
        if (fields.question == 'b') {document.getElementById('div2').style.display='block';} 
        if (fields.question == 'c') {document.getElementById('div3').style.display='block';} 

</script>
```

I apologize if this is a super simple question! Trying to learn by example. Would appreciate insight on how to achieve this. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Where are the elements with `id` starting with 'upgrade'?

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas  - my mad, the 'upgrade' should have been 'div' - updated the question to reflect.

Comment: In which case my answer should work for you; may I ask if you've tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I would store your div ID's in an object that has the `key` set to the property of `fields.question`

```
var lookup = {a:"upgrade1", b:"upgrade2", ...} //and so on
document.getElementById(lookup[fields.question]).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Hey @tymeJV - thanks, I tried doing that but I see the following error in my console:TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(lookup[fields.question]).style')

Comment: Means `fields` is null`

Comment: It turns out fields is an object and not a variable... Is that my problem do you think?

Comment: What variable is that object stored in?

Comment: Variable is called fields

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is using an object

```
var upgrades = {
    a : document.getElementById('upgrade1'),
    b : document.getElementById('upgrade2'),
    c : document.getElementById('upgrade3')
}
```

then when you want to access it to change the style

```
upgrades[fields.question].style.display='block'
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexCheuk – I tried doing this but getting the following error in my console:

Comment: [Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'upgrades[fields.question].style')

Answer (score 0):

As your question shows your `div` elements to have their `id` property with the prefix of 'div', the following code will work with that code (though in practice you may wish to change the 'div' `id`-prefix to 'upgrade'):

```
function showQuestion (details, prefix) {
    // which question:
    var q = details.question.toLowerCase(),
        // find the integer:
        n = (q.charCodeAt(0) - 97) + 1;
    // get the element, and set its display to 'block':
    document.getElementById(prefix + n).style.display = 'block';
}

var fields = {
    "age": "on",
    "email": "useremail@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "officialrules": "on",
    "question": "a"
};

// call the function, passing in the relevant object, and the 'id'-prefix
showQuestion(fields, 'div');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pgmF7/1/).

To explain the line:

```
n = (q.charCodeAt(0) - 97) + 1;
```

This takes the character (in this case the `a`), finds the unicode character point (an `a` is 97, `b` is 98, etc), and subtracts `97` from that character point which gives the 'difference' between the character used and `a`. Because you've numbered your `div` elements' `id` properties with a one-based numbering scheme, we're adding `1` to that difference.

References:

- [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Comment: Hey @David Thomas thanks but it's not working for me - please note that the var fields properties changes every time... so the "John" "Smith" "a" were just sample data. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you need to clearly show the likely structure of your expected data, and explain what, if any restrictions are placed on it. Will the `question` property always be an alphabetical character? That's the only property of relevance to the question you asked, how are the other fields relevant?

Comment: Hey David – the question property is either going to have a, b or c. There are three divs (div1, div2, div3) all set as default to display none. If the question property contains a, I want div1 to show as block. If question property contains 2, I want div2 to show as block, if question property contains 3, I want div3 to show as block. Sorry I wasn't clear earlier – let me know if this helps.

Comment: Well, yes: that's what my code does, doesn't it? I don't see where it fails.